# Nested For Loops Probably

Tags: python

```
start_month = 10
start_day = 24
end_month = 11
end_day = 28


time_stamp = []
for r in range(0,24):
    if 0 <=r <= 9:
        hr_str = '0' + str(r) + ':'
        time_stamp.append(hr_str)
    else:
        hr_str = str(r)+ ':'
        time_stamp.append(hr_str)
```

I need to loop through and make a list that has every month, day and hour time possible. I figured out the hour, as shown above, but I am not sure how to get the month and day.

Comment: Unless you are expecting some specific output, I don't see the problem?

Comment: right now, I'm only getting the hour options, and I need the day and month options as well. For example, my hoped first output would be '10-24 00' and then '10-24 01'

Comment: Hi, it would be really useful to people answering if you include a sample of the output you are wanting in the question. Second, your question title isn't actually a question but does indicate you probably already know the answer to your question. Yes, nested loops is likely the way to go. I suggest you have a go at a solution using nested loops and if you are still stuck or having a specific problem, update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a range in time, you'll need the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) functions. This is a possible way of doing it:

```
import datetime

start_month = 12
start_day = 24
end_month = 1
end_day = 28

start = datetime.datetime(2019, start_month, start_day)  # <- 2019 specified
end = datetime.datetime(2020, end_month, end_day)        # <- 2020 specified

lst = [(start + datetime.timedelta(hours=h)).strftime('%m-%d %H') for h in range((end-start).days * 24)]

for datehour in lst:
    print(datehour)
```

Comment: how would you use this if the months were the same?

Comment: Its the way range() works. Range(10,10) -> None Range(10,11) -> 10. So if you add 1 to the range, it will work. See my modified answer. Sorry, I should have seen that myself.

Comment: thank you for modifying. It is sorta working except that when it switches over, i needed it to go from day 31 to day 1 of the 11th month.

Comment: That's another type of problem. For working with real dates you'll need the datetime functions. You also need to specify a year to accommodate for possible leap years. I changed my answer once again.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!!!